# Calculating monthly mean temperature from TerraClimate

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, hydrology

I'm working on a hydrology project and need to obtain monthly average temperature data for a watershed. I'm using the TerraClimate dataset, but it only contains monthly average high and low temperatures. Where can I download monthly mean temperature data, or how can I calculate it?

Comment: If you track down the associated publication you will find that mean temperature does not exist in the TerraClimate datasets.

Comment: That's correct. What would be the best way of importing that kind of data, or calculating it?